# QuickBlox- Getting Thread Error in one to one chat

Tags: ios, quickblox

Hi I m able to authenticate as a user and i want to chat with Quick Blox Owner, so do that i have used Owner ID to chat with currently authenticated User.

My Code---

```
- (void)chatLogin
{
 QBChatDialog *chatDialog = [QBChatDialog new];    
 chatDialog.name =@"Chat With Me";    
 chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(1111)];
 chatDialog.type = QBChatDialogTypePrivate;
 [QBChat createDialog:chatDialog delegate:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self chatLogin];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.messages = [NSMutableArray array];
self.messagesTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

}
```

Code Response Result---

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result
{
if (result.success || [result isKindOfClass:QBChatHistoryMessageResult.class] || [result isKindOfClass:[QBChatDialogResult class]])
{
    QBChatDialogResult *res = (QBChatDialogResult *)result;
    QBChatDialog *dialog = res.dialog;
    NSLog(@"Dialog: %@", dialog);

   QBChatHistoryMessageResult *res1 = (QBChatHistoryMessageResult *)result;
    NSArray *messages = res1.messages;
   [self.messages addObjectsFromArray:[messages mutableCopy]];
  [self.messagesTableView reloadData];
}
}
```

Getting Error =

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '**setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: chat_dialog_id)'

*** First throw call stack:

    **(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x036bcdf6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03346a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x035b019c -[__NSDictionaryM 
    setObject:forKey:] + 940
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0362c7f0 -[NSMutableDictionary 
    setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] + 48
    4   vChat                               0x00033853 -[QBCMessageGetQuery setParams:] + 243
    5   vChat                               0x0008c415 -[QBQuery setupRequest:] + 133
    6   vChat                               0x0008c11f -[QBQuery 
    performInBgAsyncWithDelegate:] + 511
    7   Foundation                          0x02f4cb57 -[NSThread main] + 76
    8   Foundation                          0x02f4cab0 __NSThread__main__ + 1326
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03eedecf _pthread_body + 138
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03eede45 _pthread_body + 0
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03eebf0e thread_start + 34
)**
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**
```

Comment: Which version of iOS SDK do you use? I propose you to update to the latest 2.0.10. I remember this problem in earlier versions

Comment: @IgorKhomenko i have updated to 2.0.10 but same prob exists..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue is with Get Messages query

```
NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = [NSMutableDictionary new];
extendedRequest[@"limit"] = @(100);
NSString *dialogID = @"5406cba6efa357825a00002b";
[QBChat messagesWithDialogID:dialogID extendedRequest:extendedRequest delegate:self];
```

And I guess that **dialogID** is nil in your case, that's why you get an exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '**setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: chat_dialog_id)'
```

The dialogID should not be nil

Comment: yes my dialodID is nil but y i getting nil, i m already authenticating